# Puppet erb template - how do you compare two integers

Tags: ruby, operators, erb, puppet

Using puppet (3.6), I have the following erb template

```
<% if @redis_port != ''%>
  redis['port'] = <%= @redis_port %>             
<% end %>
```

The desired behavior is that if `$redis_port` is anything other than `nil` or blank, then print it out. Otherwise omit the line

```
redis['port'] = 6379
```

$redis_port is defined in the params.pp puppet manifest

```
$ cat params.pp
class foobar::params {
  $redis_port       = nil #'6379'
}

$ cat init.pp
class foobar {
  $redis_port = $foobar::params::redis_port
}
```

Why does the erb template only work correctly if $redis_port is a string?

I have tried the following combinations without luck.

---

Test Matrix:
($redis_port is from params.pp, the if statement is in the erb template)

```
$redis_port = '6379' #Success
<% if @redis_port != ''%>


$redis_port = 6379 #Fail
<% if @redis_port != ''%>


$redis_port = 6379 #Fail
<% if @redis_port %>


$redis_port = 6379 #Fail
<% if scope['::foobar::redis_port'] %>


$redis_port = 6379 #Fail
<% if @redis_port != ''%>


$redis_port = 6379 #Fail
<% if @redis_port != nil %>
```

The puppetlabs documentation shows that I should be able to simply query if the value is nil or not simply by using @redis_port.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html

---

[image]

---

Additional Resources

https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/3420/if-else-statement-in-erb-template/

Comment: First off: Doing `$varname = nil` in a **manifest** is flawed, because `nil` has no special meaning in the Puppet language. You get the string `"nil"` as a value. You want `$varname = undef`, but that to has caveats, as seen in the table you posted.

Comment: Thanks @FelixFrank your comment lead me to the right answer. I had to use undef. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central issue here is that `nil` is not a reserved word in Puppet and is considered a non-delimited string instead, representing the value `'nil'`. As the quoted documentation states, Puppet's closes analog is `undef`, therefor:

```
$redis_port = undef
```

I marvel at the failure of both `if @var` and `if @var != ''` when the manifest assigned an integer value. That should propagate to ERB either as a string representation or a numeric value, for which both expressions *should* evaluate to true (to Ruby, only `nil` and `false` are false, if I'm not mistaken).

I shall try and reproduce, this might be a bug.